# eigen() and the correct eigenvectors

Tags: r, matrix, eigenvalue, eigenvector

My problem is the following:

I'm trying to use R in order to compute numerically [this](https://brilliant.org/wiki/stationary-distributions/) problem.
So I've correctly setup the problem in my console, and then I tried to compute the eigenvectors.

[image: R program]

But I expect that the eigenvector associated with lambda = 1 is (1,2,1) instead of what I've got here. So, the scaling is correct (0.4082483 is effectively half of 0.8164966), but I would like to obtain a consistent result.

My original problem is to find a stationary distribution for a Markov Chain using R instead of doing it on paper. So from a probabilistic point of view, my stationary distribution is a vector whose sum of the components is equal to 1. For that reason I was trying to change the scale in order to obtain what I've defined "a consistent result".

How can I do that ?

Comment: can you please post your results as code-formatted text (cut and paste the text from the console, then use indentation or triple-backticks to code format) rather than images?  thanks ...

Comment: The eigen vectors are normalized. What do you mean by "consistent"? If `V` is a eigen vector then `s * V` is a eigen vector as well for any non-zero scalar `s`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The eigen vectors returned by R are normalized (for the square-norm). If `V` is a eigen vector then `s * V` is a eigen vector as well for any non-zero scalar `s`. If you want the stationary distribution as in your link, divide by the sum:

```
V / sum(V)
```

and you will get `(1/4, 1/2, 1/4)`.

So:

```
ev <- eigen(t(C))$vectors
ev / colSums(ev)
```

to get all the solutions in one shot.

Answer (score 2):

```r
C <- matrix(c(0.5,0.25,0,0.5,0.5,0.5,0,0.25,0.5),
            nrow=3)
ee <- eigen(t(C))$vectors
```

As suggested by @Stéphane Laurent in the comments, the scaling of eigenvectors is arbitrary; only the relative value is specified. The default in R is that the sum of squares of the eigenvectors (their *norms*) are equal to 1; `colSums(ee^2)` is a vector of 1s.

Following the link, we can see that you want each eigenvector to sum to 1.

```r
ee2 <- sweep(ee,MARGIN=2,STATS=colSums(ee),FUN=`/`)
```

(i.e., divide each eigenvector by its sum).

(This is a good *general* solution, but in this case the sum of the second and third eigenvectors are both approximately zero [theoretically, they are *exactly* zero], so this only really makes sense for the first eigenvector.)

Comment: He/she wants a stochastic vector eventually (as in the link).